# Rails ActiveRecord Migration not creating some columns after successful migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm creating a new model from a game, with a home team and a away team.
If i run a rake db:reset, it runs without errors, but the first three fields (home_team, away_team and league) aren't generated in the database, the other fields are ok.
This is my migrate:

```
    class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
       create_table :games do |t|
         t.references :home_team, references: :teams, foreign_key: true, index: true
         t.references :away_team, references: :teams, foreign_key: true, index: true
         t.belongs_to :league, foreign_key: true
         t.integer :round
         t.datetime :date

         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end
```

Here's is the schema.rb generated

```
      create_table "games", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
        t.integer  "round"
        t.datetime "date"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end
```

But, the most weird for me is that i have another migration for Transactions, and this works fine:

```
    class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :transactions do |t|
          t.references :from_user, references: :users, foreign_key: true, index: true
          t.references :to_user, references: :users, foreign_key: true, index: true
          t.decimal :amount        

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: You should have used `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Probably table `teams` doesn't exists. Try to avoid to use `references` and just use `t.integer` instead.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of [`add_reference`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) it feels to me like `references` doesn't care about the `references: :teams` option. Can you please point my to the documentation that you are following?

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:reset` will not run the latest migrations for you. It will run `db:drop` and `db:setup`. `db:setup` itself then runs `db:schema:load` and `db:seed`.

So in running `db:reset`, it drops the database, creates it again from your schema, and initialises the database with the seed data. It does NOT run any pending migrations.

After doing `db:reset` you will then need to run `db:migrate` to apply the pending migrations. The successfull migrations will update the schema for you so that next time you run `db:setup` or `db:reset` those migrations will automatically be applied.

If you had previously run `db:migrate` they may have failed and left your schema.rb in a 'corrupt' state. You may want to try to rollback your schema to a prior version and rerun the migrations to ensure you aren't getting any errors.

Note, this is not so much a solution, but a lengthy comment.